# Export and output another py code and send its console result with the e-mail code

Tags: python, email

I have two code, one to send e-mail (works) and another to pull information from a link (metro.py).

What I'm trying to do is:  go to the e-mail code, import the metro.py and and send the metro.py results in the e-mail body. How can I get the metro.py results and send it using the body?

i've tried to import metro and then set metro in the body text: sent_body = (metro), but it didn't work.

```py
import smtplib
import metro


gmail_user = 'email@gmail.com'
gmail_app_password = 'password'
sent_from = gmail_user
sent_to = ['receive@gmail.com']
sent_subject = "Email Teste"
sent_body = ("")

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(sent_to), sent_subject, sent_body)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_app_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, sent_to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print('Email sent!')
except Exception as exception:
    print("Error: %s!\n\n" % exception)
```

```py
METRO:

import requests
import ast


source = requests.get('http://apps.cptm.sp.gov.br:8080/AppMobileService/api/LinhasMetropolitanas')
content_list=ast.literal_eval(source.content.decode("utf-8"))
for d in content_list:
    print(d['Nome'],d['Status'])
```

I expect that I could send the output from metro via email.

Answer (score 0):

You can make metro into a function.

something like this:
    import requests
    import ast

```
def get_data():
    source = requests.get('http://apps.cptm.sp.gov.br:8080/AppMobileService/api/LinhasMetropolitanas')
    content_list=ast.literal_eval(source.content.decode("utf-8"))
    #for d in content_list:
    #   print(d['Nome'],d['Status'])
    return content_list
```

Then in your other file import the function like this `from metro import get_data`.
That should allow your code to work. *** This assumes your code files are in the same directory ***

Then to get the email body it would be something like `sent_body = get_data()` or you can do some processing on the data since it is just returing the raw results.

Comment: But now I'm getting that output: 
"Error: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 96-97: ordinal not in range(128)!"

Comment: What line is throwing that error? it likely to do with the data having some strange unicode character, so you can try looking up some different methods for handling ascii or unicode data. If you can't figure that out, it may be worth asking a new question.